# how to get xy coordinate of an image after drag and drop in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem getting the x y coordinates of a rectangle.

Actually I already get the x y coordinate, but it is not correct.. I used visual studio 2008.. n using jquery..ok, the design is like this:

I had a div name "drg".. that is a big box.. inside the div(the big box) there is an image that is the rectangle. I drag the rectangle to the end top left of the div but the result for x=8, n y=8.. Logically the code  counts from the out of the div.. Thats why got x=10 n y=10.

I want when drag to the end top left of the div, the result must be x=0,y=0..

This is my code: "im" is the id of image(red box)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // sets draggable the elements with id="im"
    $('#im').draggable({
        cursor: 'move',        // sets the cursor apperance
        containment: '#drg', 

        stop : function(){
            $("#value").text('x-axis :' + $('#im').offset().left + 'y-axis :' + $('#im').offset().top);

            var imgPosX = 10 - $("img#im").width();
            var imgPosY = 10 - $("img#im").height();

        }
    });
});
```

When I drag the image(red box)to the top left, it get x=8,y=8...it counts from out of the blue box..I want it to count from in the blue box n get x=0,y=0 if the position of the image(red box) is like that.

Answer (score 3):

```
stop: function(event, ui) {

        // Show dropped position.
        var Stoppos = $(this).position();
        var left = Math.abs(Stoppos.left);
        var top = Math.abs(Stoppos.top);
    }
```

You can also make it within `drag()` event like

```
   drag: function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = Math.abs(offset.left);
        var yPos = Math.abs(offset.top);
        $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
    }
```

**[Complete demo with above two events](http://jsfiddle.net/DGbT3/416/)**

#### According to comment

As you don't want negative value so use `Math.abs()` to make all value positive.

Comment: but, I dont want to have a negative value..just want the position of the image..meaning that, if I drag the image left or right, up or down, I got the coordinate of x n y but not the negative sign in front, just want the value..

Comment: ...can u please help me...I've got the coordinate xy of the image like in the demo..but now I edit the demo.I want the square box to be drag in another big box..but when I drag the square box to the end of the big box, it gives the coordinate x=8,y=8 instead of x=0,y=0 because it counts starts from out of the box to the square box...please help me...I want it to be x=0,y=0...

Comment: @Farahfathiah please post your demo in fiddle